# Parametrized family of classes

Tags: c#, class, parameters, static-methods

I'd like to build a family of classes that

- solely do calculations (i.e. instances of the classes are not needed)
- all do the same calculations but differ in a parameter, which is hardcoded into each class.

Based on the thread https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/325213/237600 , I came up with this:

```
public abstract class PrecisionSpace
{
    protected static double TOL; // This value is supposed to be
                                 // different in subclasses, so that...

    public static bool TolEquals(double left, double right) // ... this method, ...
    {
        return (Math.Abs(left - right) <= TOL);
    }

    public static bool TolSmaller(double left, double right) // ... this method and ...
    {
        return (left + TOL < right);
    }

    public static bool TolLarger(double left, double right) // ... this method behave
                                                            //     differently.
    {
        return TolSmaller(right, left);
    }
}
```

Then I'd like to define subclasses

```
public class PerfectPrecision : PrecisionSpace
{
    (new) private static double 0; // doesn't matter if I put "new" in front or not
} 

public class MyPrecision: PrecisionSpace
{
    (new) private static double 1E-10;
}
```

and be able to use statements like

```
bool foo = MyPrecision.TolEquals(0, 1E-11); // supposed to be true
```

but it doesn't work as I want, because the `TOL` values in the subclasses are not utilized in the static methods of `PrecisionSpace`. So no matter which subclass `T` I put for `T.TolEquals(...)`, the compiler always uses the value defined in the superclass `PrecisionSpace` (which is the default value for `double`, i.e. `0`).

In short, `static` fields cannot be overridden. So what can I do?

I could drop all `static` modifiers and set the desired `TOL` values in the constructors of the derived classes. But then I'd always need to have instances of the classes. Since I'm not really going to need instances, I could make the classes singleton. But then I have to make sure it is thread-safe and such... Meh.

What else?

I could write unrelated classes in the same way as `PrecisionSpace`, with static methods, substituting `TOL` for `0` or `1E-10` or whatever value I choose per class. But this makes a lot of redundant code, and since the classes don't have a common base class or interface, I cannot define generics properly, like this:

```
public class MyVector<T> where T : (base class or interface of the Precision classes)
```

Any other ideas? Something with delegates maybe?

To those who ask "why": Please read the thread linked at the beginning of my question.

Comment: Your plan of using `interface of the Precision classes` will not work as an interface cannot declare static methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In .NET 6+ this can be achieved using [static abstract members in interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-11.0/static-abstracts-in-interfaces). It can go even further and use generic math to abstract the data type (`double`):

```cs
interface IPrecisionSpace<TNumber> where TNumber : INumber<TNumber>
{
    static abstract TNumber TOL { get; }
}

static class PrecisionSpace<TNumber, TPrecision> where TNumber : INumber<TNumber> where TPrecision : IPrecisionSpace<TNumber>
{
    public static bool TolEquals(TNumber left, TNumber right)
    {
        return TNumber.Abs(left - right) <= TPrecision.TOL;
    }

    public static bool TolSmaller(TNumber left, TNumber right)
    {
        return left + TPrecision.TOL < right;
    }

    public static bool TolLarger(TNumber left, TNumber right)
    {
        return TolSmaller(right, left);
    }
}

class Vector<TNumber, TPrecision> where TNumber : INumber<TNumber> where TPrecision : IPrecisionSpace<TNumber>
{
    public Vector(TNumber number)
    {
        var isZero = PrecisionSpace<TNumber, TPrecision>.TolEquals(TNumber.Zero, number);
    }
}

class DoublePerfectPrecision : IPrecisionSpace<double>
{
    public static double TOL => 0;
}

class DoubleMyPrecision : IPrecisionSpace<double>
{
    public static double TOL => 1E-10;
}
```

Usage: `new Vector<double, DoublePerfectPrecision>(value: 1)`

---

Earlier versions doesn't support inheritance on static members. If you want polymorphic behavior, you're going to have to create instances. Thread-safety shouldn't be an issue at all if your classes are built to be immutable.

```cs
    public abstract class PrecisionSpace
    {
        private readonly double TOL;
        
        protected PrecisionSpace(double tol) { TOL = tol; }
    
        public bool TolEquals(double left, double right)
        {
            return (Math.Abs(left - right) <= TOL);
        }
    }
    
    public sealed class PerfectPrecision : PrecisionSpace
    {
        public PerfectPrecision() : base(0) { }
    }
    
    internal static class PrecisionSpaceCache<T> where T : PrecisionSpace, new()
    {
        public static readonly T Instance = new T();
    }
    
    public class MyVector<T> where T : PrecisionSpace, new()
    {
        public void Foo(double x, double y)
        {
            PrecisionSpaceCache<T>.Instance.TolEquals(x, y);
        }
    }
```

This way you can use `PrecisionSpaceCache` in other classes (e.g. `Matrix`). In addition, I'd consider turning all the vector, matrix, etc. classes into value types (`struct`) if you plan on creating a lot of them.

Another option is to just pass the precision in the Vector class's constructor.

Comment: "Another option is to just pass the precision in the Vector class's constructor." That is unfortunately not an option because then vectors with different tolerances would be compatible, which I do not want. In fact, having vectors with different tolerances behaving like different types is what I really want - and the above question emerged from this need.

Comment: Good point. But I also have classes `Matrix`, `Point`, `Polygon`... if I work with vectors of tolerance 1E-10 and want to combine them with the other classes (of same tolerance), I'd need to derive from these classes also. Seems not very clean to me.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question. What I want is: a vector with tolerance x is incompatible to a vector of tolerance y (if x != y), they should be considered different types. Also, a vector with tolerance x is compatible to matrices, points, polygons (and other classes to be added later) iff they also have tolerance x. As I understand, if I define a subclass `VectorOfTol0` for tolerance 0, I need to define subclasses `MatrixOfTol0`, `PointOfTol0` and so on. Whenever I add a new type like `Line`, I also need to make subclasses of `Line` for all tolerances ever used.

Comment: Can you explain why you suggest turning the vectors, matrices and so on into structs?

Comment: I like this approach. Do you know how to make sure that instantiating `PerfectPrecision` can only take place inside `PrecisionSpaceCache`? Not by nesting classes inside `PrecisionSpaceCache`, because this approach is not extendible for a user of my code (if the `PrecisionSpaceCache` class is fixed).

Answer (score 0):

In the base .net framework the best approximation of what you are trying to do is the series of Double, Int etc. classes which expose the same methods but operate on different data types and give different results.

Where the features are the same (ToString for instance) the framework uses a shared static class that it calls to carry out the function. This cuts down the amount of coding but does not use inheritance etc. to cut down the number of end points.

Answer (score 0):

If it is all about the syntactic convenience and other considerations are not important, you can achieve the desired effect by using a generic class as its own argument as follows, permitting you to internally instantiate it in a static method, as follows.

```
public class Precision<T> where T : Precision<T>, new()
{
    protected virtual double TOL
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public static bool TolEquals(double left, double right)
    {
        return (Math.Abs(left - right) <= new T().TOL);
    }
}
```

In the derived classes you would override the virtual method.

```
public class PerfectPrecision : Precision<PerfectPrecision>
{
    protected override double TOL
    {
        get { return 0.00f; }
    }
}

public class MyPrecision : Precision<MyPrecision>
{
    protected override double TOL
    {
        get { return 0.01f; }
    }
}
```

This has the desired effect, which can be verified as follows.

```
Console.WriteLine(PerfectPrecision.TolEquals(0.000f, 0.0001f));
Console.WriteLine(MyPrecision.TolEquals(0.000f, 0.0001f));
```

However, this comes at some cost. The generation of class instances to be able to benefit from inheritance are only invisible to the caller, they take place nevertheless. Furthermore, the classes do not actually derive from the same base class, as they use different type parameters.

Comment: This seems to have quite a lot of cost. Whenever I call `TolEquals`, a new instance of `T` is generated. We could put a `private static T t` field into `Precision<T>` and only instantiate it once, but then it's kind of singleton again...